# Why does casting Python's map() function change its effect?

Tags: python, set

Recently I've been learning python and I have been working with Sets and the map function.
I noticed some behavior that I don't quite understand.
Say I have the code:

```
1 A = set()
2 l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
3 
4 map(A.add, l)
```

From my understanding of map, all line 4 should do is return an iterator over the function A.add() on each element of l, thus not actually modifying A (Which it doesn't as expected).

However, if I replace line 4 with: `set(map(A.add, l))` or `list(map(A.add, l))` or even `tuple(map(A.add, l))`, A is now modified to the set `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`. Why does simply casting the return value of map change what happens to A?

My guess as to why this is happening is that line 4 in the first example is simply creating the iterator whereas when I cast it the iterator is actually iterated through in order to perform the cast, thus actually making the A.add() function calls and populating A with the expected values.

Comment: Try to forget the word "cast" - it rarely applies in Python. `set()`, `list()`, and `tuple()`  are functions that wholly materialize an iterable argument (whether the result of a `map()` or anything else) to construct a container object of the appropriate type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try looking at it this way:

```
A = set()
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 
m = map(A.add, l)

print(A)
# empty set

next(m) # calls A.add(1)
print(A)
# {1}

next(m) # calls A.add(2)
print(A) 
# {1, 2}
```

Using `map()` creates an iterator that will lazily evaluate the function on each call to `next()`. The function `A.add()` will certainly effect `A` — that's what it's supposed to do — but it only gets called once each time `next()` is called. *Until* `next()` is called, **nothing happens**.

Passing `m` to something like `list()` will cause it to go through the whole list — it's the same as calling `next()` until you run out of values. So all the values will be passed one at a time to `A.add()`. The result is all the values get added to `A`.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding:

The map() function returns a Map object. This Map object is an iterator that will apply the operation on each element *once iterated*. When you call map(A.add, l), you're creating the iterator but not actually iterating.

Now, the set() function is actually a constructor. It can iterate through an iterable and add each item to the new set. However, in this instance, your map object isn't returning anything, it's modifying A.

```
>>> set(map(A.add, l))
{None}
```

We see that the result set has a single None, because that's all the map object returned (it actually returned 5 Nones which got set'd down to one). However, A has now been modified since the map has performed its operations.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of `map` is incorrect. From the docs for `map`:

> Return an iterator that **applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results**. If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel. With multiple iterables, the iterator stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted. For cases where the function inputs are already arranged into argument tuples, see itertools.starmap().

The equivalent of `map` with just loops would be:

```
def map_with_loops(fn, iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        yield fn(item)
```

This means that your examples will evaluate to the following:

```
a = set()
l = [1, 2, 3]

# Doesn't do anything since add has not been consumed yet
map(a.add, l)

# adds all elements of l to a and evaluates to [None, None, None]
list(map(a.add, l))

# adds all elements of l to a and evaluates to {None}
set(map(a.add, l))
```

Answer (score 0):

`set add` isn't a very good example for use of `map`:

```
In [20]: A = set()                                                                      
In [21]: alist = [1,2,3,4]                                                              
In [22]: A.add(1)           # modifies A, returns None                                                                       
In [23]: A.add(2)                                                                       
In [24]: A                                                                              
Out[24]: {1, 2}
In [25]: list(map(A.add, alist))                                                        
Out[25]: [None, None, None, None]
```

The correct way(s) to add a list to a set are:

```
In [26]: set(alist)          # populate a set from a list                                                           
Out[26]: {1, 2, 3, 4}

In [28]: A = set()                                                                      
In [29]: A.update(alist)                                                                
In [30]: A                                                                              
Out[30]: {1, 2, 3, 4}

In [31]: A = set()                                                                      
In [32]: A.update(alist)                                                                
In [33]: A                                                                              
Out[33]: {1, 2, 3, 4}

In [34]: A = set()                                                                      
In [35]: for i in alist: A.add(i)                                                       
In [36]: A                                                                              
Out[36]: {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Use of `map` (or a list comprehension) just for the side effects, and not for the returned value, is discouraged (but not prohibited).

But using `map` with a function that returns a new value is fine:

```
In [37]: g = map(float, alist)                                                          
In [38]: g                                                                              
Out[38]: <map at 0x7f78bd07fc18>      # unevaluated map
In [39]: list(g)                      # evaluate/iterate                                                  
Out[39]: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

`tuple` and `set` work as well.

```
In [40]: tuple(map(float, alist))                                                       
Out[40]: (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)

In [41]: set(map(float, alist))                                                         
Out[41]: {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
```

If it helps you can think of these as `set(list(map(float, alist)))`.  Python might not actually populate the list, but there's no harm in thinking that way.

Personally I prefer the clarity of a list comprehension (or generator expression).

```
In [42]: [float(i) for i in alist]  
Out[42]: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]  
In [43]: {float(i) for i in alist}                                                      
Out[43]: {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
In [46]: tuple(float(i) for i in alist)                                                 
Out[46]: (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
```

Almost anything that takes an `iterable` (or sequence) as argument can work with a map, a generator expression, or list.